# Convexity for Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

We consider a r.v. $X$ that satisfies $0 \leq X \leq 1$ a.s. and a sample of $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ with the same distribution as $X$. We denote by $\mu= E[X]$ and we let $\lambda >0$.

I need to use convexity of the exponential function to show that the following inequality holds a.s.: $$e^{\lambda X}\leq X+ (1-X) e^{\lambda}$$

What expression for $\lambda X$ do I need to use in order to get the above ?

Comment: What about $e^{0\cdot X+\lambda \cdot(1-X)}$ compared to $X\cdot e^0 + (1-X)\cdot e^\lambda$?

Comment: The inequality is wrong, take for example $X = 1$ and an arbitrary $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Indeed -- you need the $(1-X)$ in the exponent of the RHS, here it appears you mixed the coefficients. If the coefficient of $\lambda$ is $X$ in the LHS, then the coefficient of $e^\lambda$ should be $X$ on the RHS.